# Error - Facebook SDK not initialised on Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I followed Facebook quick start guide to link up facebook sdk with the android app in order to use the graph api. Completed all the steps and on running, it shows invalid app id.

```
2020-08-19 13:09:42.254 19754-19807/com.example.posttofb E/GraphResponse: {HttpStatus: 400, errorCode: 100, subErrorCode: 33, errorType: GraphMethodException, errorMessage: Unsupported get request. Object with ID '###########' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation.
```

This was the manifest:

```
    <application
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>
```

Changed the manifest to `android:resource="@string/facebook_app_id"` and it now asks to use `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` even thought the method is deprecated.

```
2020-08-19 13:03:38.034 19271-19271/com.example.posttofb E/MainActivity: error in message posting
    The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
        at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:146)
        at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.getApplicationContext(FacebookSdk.java:603)
```

The code to post image :

```
public void post() {
        try {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newPostRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    "/{group-id}/feed",
                    new JSONObject("{\"message\":\"Posting from android studio.\"}"),
                    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.v("MainActivity","error in message posting");
                        }
                    });
            request.executeAsync();

        }
```

Comment: What version of facebook sdk are you using?

Comment: The latest version `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.15.3`

Answer (score 0):

did you add `FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize()` in application.java file?

Comment: it is no longer required to add this.

Comment: I tried this nevertheless, and it now shows the following error even though the id is stored in strings.xml: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.posttofb/com.example.posttofb.MainActivity}: App Ids cannot be directly placed in the manifest.They must be prefixed by 'fb' or be placed in the string resource file.`

Comment: do you had definition the com.example.posttofb.MainActivity in the manifest.xml ?

Comment: Still getting the error with RN 0.70.6 after upgrading